# Tradução WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

Olá, estou utilizando o WordPress a alguns meses e estou enfrentando um pequeno problema quanto a tradução de alguns termos do Woocommerce.
[image: imagem do erro de tradução]

Eis a imagem, essa página é a de visualização do produto. Vejam que todas as informações estão em português, porém tem essa que continua "Product Description".
Já instalei o Loco Translate, mas ele mostra que já está tudo traduzido. O que na prática não acontece.
Já busquei ajuda, pesquisei mas até agora nada. Se puderem me ajudar ficarei grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentei usar o Loco Translate porém não obtive sucesso. A solução que encontrei foi ir no diretório e alterar manualmente. O diretório é esse:

wp-content/themes/nome-do-tema-ativo/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php

Como o meu tema é o **salient**, ficou :
wp-content/themes/**salient**/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php